# MusicDb Not Available - Data Stax Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I am going through self paced training provided by Data Stax and I have downloaded CCM tool to get started, but in my list of keyspaces I am not able to see "MusicDB" which is used for training purposes. Any one has faced the same issue, if yes, please help

Comment: Are you using the Virtual Machine image or did you set up the environment yourself? The sample DB is available in their virtual image as sample data.

Comment: Oh Ok.. I am using my own setup. I though it comes with CCM. That's fine.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

CCM is Cassandra Cluster Manager and not the MusicDB sample database. I am unable to find the import script for the MusicDB sample collection but if you use the set up on the virtual machine that can be [downloaded here](https://academy.datastax.com/courses/ds220-data-modeling) (after logging in), you could export the data if you really wanted to use it in your own instance.